# Android webview loads page in onResume only, not in onCreate

Tags: android, android-webview, onresume

My give URL doesn't load with this code, however if I press 'home' key and click on app icon again(ie. resuming my activity) then it loads. I tried looking into activity lifecycle, tinkered with code but still it doesn't work. Please let me know if I need to clarify my question further. Thanks.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView.SavedState;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ABC.R;
import com.ABC.util.CustomProgressDialogs;
import com.ABC.util.DeviceCheck;
import com.ABC.util.GlobalFunction;
import com.ABC.util.HTML5WebView;
import com.ABC.util.KeyBoard;
import com.ABC.util.NetworkCheck;

public class CanvasActivity extends Activity {

    private HTML5WebView mWebView;
    private ProgressDialog webPageDialog;
    private Context context;
    private GlobalFunction globalFunc;
    private KeyBoard keyBoard;
    private BroadcastReceiver connectionReceiver;
    String myUrl;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    Log.d("killapp", "killapp");
                                    globalFunc.killApplication(context);
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
            AlertDialog exitDialog = builder.create();
            exitDialog.show();
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = CanvasActivity.this;
        mWebView = new HTML5WebView(context);
        // setContentView(mWebView.getLayout());
        final DeviceCheck deviceCheck = new DeviceCheck(context); // change
        // mWebView = new HTML5WebView(this);
        // getWindow().requestFeature(Window.);
        // setContentView()
        // getWindow().
        setContentView(mWebView.getLayout());
        globalFunc = new GlobalFunction();
        webPageDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                Log.d("onReceivedError", failingUrl + " " + errorCode);
                mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html");

            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                    SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
                Log.d("onReceivedSslError", "ssl error");
                handler.proceed();
                // To supercede SSL certificate error.
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                Log.d("page started", "page loading started");
                webPageDialog.show();
                webPageDialog.setContentView(CustomProgressDialogs
                        .iphoneProgressDialog(context));
                webPageDialog.setCancelable(true);

                // change

                webPageDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        webPageDialog.dismiss();
                        globalFunc.killApplication(context);
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, final String url) {
                Log.i("onPageFinished", "onPageFinished");
                if (webPageDialog.isShowing()) {
                    webPageDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        if (getIntent().getStringExtra("Message") != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getIntent().getIntExtra("push details", 0) + "",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        keyBoard = new KeyBoard(mWebView, context);
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(keyBoard, "KeyBoard");

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

        /*
         * if(prefs.getString("url",
         * getResources().getString(R.string.MYURL_URL)).trim().equals("")){
         * myUrl=getResources().getString(R.string.MYURL_URL).trim(); }else{
         * myUrl = prefs.getString("url",
         * getResources().getString(R.string.MYURL_URL)).trim(); }
         * mWebView.loadUrl(myUrl);
         */
        myUrl = getResources().getString(R.string.MYURL_URL).trim();
        /*
         * if (!myUrl.equalsIgnoreCase(prefs.getString("url",
         * getResources().getString(R.string.MYURL_URL)).trim())) {
         * 
         * myUrl = prefs.getString("url",
         * getResources().getString(R.string.MYURL_URL)).trim();
         * 
         * }
         */
        // mWebView.loadUrl(myUrl);

        if (new NetworkCheck(context).isOnline()) {

            // change

            webPageDialog.show();
            webPageDialog.setContentView(CustomProgressDialogs
                    .iphoneProgressDialog(context));
            webPageDialog.setCancelable(true);
            webPageDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    webPageDialog.dismiss();
                    globalFunc.killApplication(context);
                }
            });

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
            } else {
                mWebView.loadUrl(myUrl);
                /*
                 * if (deviceCheck.isTablet()) {
                 * setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo
                 * .SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); mWebView.loadUrl(myUrl); }
                 * else {
                 * setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
                 * ); mWebView.loadUrl(myUrl); }
                 */
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
            mWebView.loadUrl(myUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!((prefs.getString("url",
                getResources().getString(R.string.MYURL_URL)).trim()))
                .equals("")) {
            myUrl = prefs.getString("url",
                    getResources().getString(R.string.MYURL_URL)).trim();
        }
        if (!(myUrl.equals(mWebView.getUrl()))) {
            // mWebView.loadUrl(myUrl);
        }

        /*
         * if (!mWebView.getUrl().equalsIgnoreCase(prefs.getString("url",
         * getResources().getString(R.string.MYURL_URL)).trim())) {
         * 
         * myUrl = prefs.getString("url",
         * getResources().getString(R.string.MYURL_URL)).trim();
         * mWebView.loadUrl(myUrl); }
         */
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mWebView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d("CanvasActivity-onOptionsItemSelected", "in option selected");
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.url:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, EditURL.class));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        Log.d("CanvasActivity-onCreateOptionsMenu",
                "in oncreate option menu");
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuxml, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mWebView.stopLoading();
    }

    // onkeydown was here.

    public void startBroadcastService() {
        connectionReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager
                        .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                ConnectivityManager connManager1 = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo mMobile = connManager1
                        .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
                boolean isNoNetwork = intent.getBooleanExtra(
                        ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
                if (!isNoNetwork) {
                    if (mWifi.isAvailable()) {
                    }
                    if ((mWifi.isConnected() && mWifi.isAvailable())
                            || (mMobile.isConnected() && mMobile.isAvailable())) {
                        if (mWebView.getUrl().contains("myerrorpage")) {
                            mWebView.loadUrl(myUrl);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(connectionReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
    }
}
```

Comment: It must be going in if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
            } else {
                mWebView.loadUrl(myUrl); 's if part. Did you debug?

Comment: Yes it is going in there but it says savedInstanceState is null, so it goes in 'else' part of that if statement. Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a handler and loaded my URL after my webview is registered in that handler with relevent functions( onPageStarted onPageFinished and onReceivedError) , because my webview was taking much time to load the page. This worked.

```
  handler = new Handler();
                jsInterface = new JSInterface(mWebView, context, uniqueGeneratedkey,
                        handler);
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        jsInterface.initiateProcess();
    /*where initiateProcess() is the method where I register all the overridden
     *functions ie. OnPageStarted() and OnPageFinished();
     */   
                    }
                });
    mWebview.LoadUrl(url);
```